# Using Node's Passport to authenticate an Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, oauth

I have a fully functional web app, where authentication was created using Passport. The application uses client-side, cookie-based session token. Basically, when a new session happens, the client's data is stored as Base64 AND signed client-side, so that the user cannot change it.

The login/pass mechanism obviously works 100% fine. Facebook, however, doesn't. The main issue is that in a web environment, the user is expected to get redirected to the Facebook page and which is passed the redirect URL to which the token is passed etc.

In a App environment, this doesn't happen: my (basic) understanding is that the client handles the whole oauth mechanism, and it is meant to provide the server with the userID and auth token -- which must then be checked by the server using a Facebook API.

So... is there a known "path" to go from "Web based Facebook login using passport" to "App based Facebook login using passport"? Or shall I not bother with Passport at all for the app side of things?